# What is the right way to define parameters in PowerShell functions?

Tags: powershell

I have seen these two versions of defining parameters in PowerShell functions:

```
 Function Get-Foo($a, $b, $c) {  
     # code...
 }
```

and

```
 Function Get-Bar {
     param($a, $b, $c)
     # code...
 }
```

- Are they functionally identical?
- If they are the same; Which one is the "right" one to use? (readability, coding standards,..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like you to go through the Powershell Documentations.

Go through the Introduction as well as the examples to have a clear understanding. 
I would still prefer the *1st method of passing any parameters* and slowly I would recommend you to move towards advanced Powershell Functions which has a much more defined structure.

Hope It helps

Comment: Yes, now I know that they work the same. I think the first one is more readable when you have a short list of parameters. How do I determine if I should use an advanced function or a basic function?

Comment: @Lerkes: It obviously depends on the requirement but still lets say if you want some of the parameters as mandate, then you have to use _(Mandatory=$true)_, similarly if you are concerned about position of parameters, then you have to use `PositionalBinding`.. So these all slowly will lead you to **advanced function**. Please accept the answer if it suffice.

Comment: okey, if you need the functionality you are obviously forced to switch to an advanced function. But I have seen that you can for example add Write-Verbose for verbose logging and wanted to know if there a guideline when to use such functionality.

Comment: @Lerkes : Consider Ed Wilson blog then always, Here is a best practice guide for _write-verbose_ [Link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/30/use-powershell-to-write-verbose-output/) :)

Comment: I would recommend to always use latter for very simple reason: it works for all types of PowerShell commands. Former works for functions/workflows only. Scripts, script blocks, configurations can handle param block only. The only place where I would use the method syntax is in actual methods (v5 classes).